# Mobile Charging Input is DC Output is DC

Tags: batteries, capacitor, charger

I want to design a circuit for mobile charging.
Input is 
Dc voltage: 0.77; 
Dc current: 0.44;
Input should be stored for 24 hours in the battery.  Output i need it for only 1 hour for charging purpose.

Output should be 
Dc voltage: 4.75
Dc Current: 0.95

Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: _"I want to design a circuit"_, ok, go ahead! Come back when you have a question to answer. (Or: this is not a design service)

Comment: Question is too broad and is probably is going to be put on hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to try to use a low voltage high impedance source to charge a higher voltage low impedance battery.  Additional charge control design is needed to limit battery voltage and limit input draw current.

[image]

Don't expect more than 60% efficiency

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I need to model this circuit in order to get useful information. But i tried to model it using OrCAD but the component TPS61200 is missing.  Is there any software to model this circuit.